# Regex match: does not contain char on beginning of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

**Abstraction problem**:

Match strings that do not start with 'char' and return matches.

**My regex** (not perfect):

```
/(<XX>){1}([^#]*)(<\/XX>){1}/ig
```

**does**:

```
<XX>#test</XX> // not matched
<XX>test</XX> // matched + return 'test'
<XX>te#st</XX> // not matched
```

**but should do**:

```
<XX>#test</XX> // not matched
<XX>test</XX> // matched + return test
<XX>te#st</XX> // matched + return te#st
```

*plus* return the fragment (i.e. group between tags = 'test', for example by '$2').

**Problem example**:
https://www.regex101.com/r/vT9kS7/1

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Comment: javascript, but it does not matter

Comment: Your requirement says "match strings which doesn't contain char", is the # the char you're trying to match?

Comment: 1. `string` doesn't contain `#` = match
2. return this (1) `fragment` of the `string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<XX>(?!#)(.*)<\/XX>
```

instead of:

```
(<XX>){1}([^#]*)(<\/XX>){1}
```

You can check out the updated regex in a [fork of your fiddle](https://www.regex101.com/r/zM5fY0/1).

Highlights:

- `(?!#)` is a negative lookahead – *not `#`*.
- "Fragment" is pretty general: so I assumed nothing with `.` (in `(.*)`).
- I dropped the first and last capturing groups in your original regex (i.e. replaced `(<XX>)` and `(<\/XX>)` with `<XX>` and `<\/XX>` respectively).  If you don't need capturing groups, don't use them.
- I dropped the explicit quantifier `{1}` from your original regex.  Both instances of it are unnecessary too.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description and test cases, the following works:

```
/(<XX>)([^#].*)(<\/XX>)/ig
```

The following regex:

```
/(<XX>)([^#].*|)(<\/XX>)/ig
```

would also allow the case of an empty `<XX></XX>`.